# Prerequisites for studying Perelman's proof of the Geometrization Conjecture

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I want to set a course toward understanding Perelman's proof of the Geometrization Conjecture. I realize this will be a lengthy undertaking, but hopefully only on the order of one to two years.

I am currently studying John Lee's [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9982-5) and Steven Weintraub's [Fundamentals of Algebraic Topology](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781493918430). I will be taking a graduate course on 4-manifolds next semester.

Could you please suggest (1) which subject areas I should study toward this eventual goal and (2) any texts you particularly like?

Comment: Off-topic: You may like [the video "Ricci Flow" by Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwOCqA9Xw6A) about this topic...

Comment: I have heard that this article (http://www.ims.cuhk.edu.hk/~ajm/vol10/10_2.pdf) of Cau and Zhu is complete (as the title sugests)

Comment: This one too: https://math.berkeley.edu/~lott/gt-2008-12-059p.pdf

Comment: This course may be helpful to you: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/285g.1.08s/

Comment: Given the prominent role played by Ricci flow, PDE theory is going to be pretty important.

Comment: This MSRI course on Ricci Flow may interest you, https://www.msri.org/summer_schools/351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the canonical reference is the book "Geometrisation of 3-manifolds" by Laurent Bessières, Gérard Besson, Michel Boileau,
Sylvain Maillot and Joan Porti. It is freely available on Besson's web page: [here](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~besson/book.pdf).

The whole purpose of this book is to present a full detailed proof of geometrisation, based of course (partly) on Perelman's work, but made as comprehensible as possible. Of course, it may still require you to consult other references to understand it, but the book does provide many references.